# how to add one random letter to a string every loop?

Tags: python

Using Python, what is the code for this?

- Prints 3 random letters.
- The player will be asked to input the 3 random letters shown.
- If the player is correct, the program will print 4 random letters *(different from the previous pattern)*
- If the player is still correct, the program will print 5 letters *(different from the previous pattern)*
- If the player answers correctly, the process repeats but with a longer pattern *(different from the previous pattern)*
- if the player is incorrect, the program will stop.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

The pattern is:

a f c

What is the pattern shown?:  *Insert player's input*

That is correct!

The pattern is:

g h t k

What is the pattern shown?:  *Insert player's input*

Sorry, that is incorrect!

** end of program **

```
def easyLevel():
i = 0
pattern = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
for i in range (5):
    pattern = pattern + " " + random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    print("The pattern is: ")
    print(pattern)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    easyAns = str(input("What was the pattern?: "))

    if easyAns == pattern:
        i = i + 1
        print("That's correct!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, that's incorrect.")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you have not imported `random`, `time`, or `string`. But I assume you would, so let's move on. Another issue is that it is confusing and unnecessary to force the player to wait 5 seconds before they can input what they see, so I suggest deleting it.

Now for the main issue.

Setting `i=0` and then saying `for i in range(5)` does not work, because the for loop assigns values to `i` each time it goes through the loop. Identically, then doing `i = i + 1` does nothing either because the assigned values in the for loop will depend solely on the loop itself.

What you could do is set another variable denoting the length of the text, and put that as the `range( )`. So the code would be:

```
import random, string


def easyLevel():
    n = 3  # Initial n
    
    while True:
        pattern = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        for i in range(n-1):  # Note here i and n are different, so setting n will actuall work
            pattern = pattern + " " + random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
            
        print("The pattern is: ")
        print(pattern)
        easyAns = str(input("What was the pattern?: "))

        if easyAns == pattern:
            n = n + 1  # Increase length of word
            print("That's correct!")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that's incorrect.")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

From python, you can't increment the `i` variable from within a for loop. Consider using a while loop. You should also regenerate the random string in each iteration. Consider using `random.choices` (with an s at the end), which can pick several values from an iterable with replacement.

```py
def easyLevel():
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        pattern = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=i+1)
        print("The pattern is: ")
        print(pattern)
        time.sleep(5)
    
        easyAns = str(input("What was the pattern?: "))

        if easyAns == pattern:
            i = i + 1
            print("That's correct!")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that's incorrect.")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!
I fixed your program for you. Here it is:

```
import random
import string
import time

def easyLevel():

    while True:
        pattern = " ".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=i+1))
        print("The pattern is: ")
        print(pattern)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        easyAns = str(input("What was the pattern?: "))

        if easyAns == pattern:
            print("That's correct!")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that's incorrect.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    easyLevel()
```